# How to solve $x\log(x) = 10^6$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve

$$x\log(x) = 10^6$$

but can't find an elegant solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: [Related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406707/elegant-way-to-solve-n-log-2n-le-106)

Answer (score 8):

Let $y=\log(x)$. Then the equation is
$$ye^y=10^6.$$
The [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is defined such that this means $y=W(10^6)$, and therefore $x=e^{W(10^6)}$.
(This is effectively just a notational trick; it doesn't make anything more explicit).

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple solution (as you have found out), your only way out is using a numerical method to solve the equation, e.g. [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Answer (score 3):

You won't find a "nice" answer, since this is a transcendental equation (no "algebraic" solution).  There *is* a special function related to this called the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), defined by  $ \ z = W(z) \cdot e^{W(z)} \ $ .  The "exact" answer to your equation is
$ \ x = e^{W( [\ln 10] \cdot 10^6)} \ . $  (I'm assuming you're using the base-10 logarithm here; otherwise you can drop the $ \ln 10 $ factor.)